# AngularJS : update parent scope from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angular controller and directive

Controller

```
app.controller('gridController',['$scope',function($scope){                     
                    $scope.btns=false;
                    $scope.details_tab=false;
                    $scope.currentid={id:''};
                    $scope.setId=function(id){
                        $scope.currentid=id;
                    };
}]);
```

Directive

```
       .directive('jqGrid',function(){

                    return{
                        restrict: 'E',
                        //require: 'ngModel',

                        link:function(scope, element, attrs){
                            jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                                data : scope.jqgrid_data,
                                datatype : "local",
                                height : 'auto',
                                colNames : ['case', 'Name', 'Assigned Date'],
                                colModel : [
                                    { name : 'act', index:'act', sortable:false }, 
                                    { name : 'id', index : 'id' }, 
                                    { name : 'date', index : 'date', editable : true }, 
                                    { name : 'name', index : 'name', editable : true }, 
                                    { name : 'amount', index : 'amount', align : "right", editable : true }, 
                                    { name : 'tax', index : 'tax', align : "right", editable : true }, 
                                    { name : 'total', index : 'total', align : "right", editable : true }, 
                                    { name : 'note', index : 'note', sortable : false, editable : true }],
                                rowNum : 10,
                                rowList : [10, 20, 30],
                                pager : '#pjqgrid',
                                sortname : 'id',
                                toolbarfilter: true,
                                viewrecords : true,
                                sortorder : "asc",
                                gridComplete: function(){

                                },
                                multiselect : true,
                                autowidth : true,
                                onSelectRow : function (rowid, status) {
                                              scope.btns=true;
                                               scope.details_tab=true;
                                                scope.currentid='';
                                                }

        })}});
```

html :

```
            <jq-grid jqdata="jqgrid_data">
                <table id="jqgrid" ></table>
            </jq-grid>
```

Here in the directive i want to update the variable in the scope
It gets updated in the local scope but not in the controller scope.How can i update scope directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this issue with

```
           scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `scope: true` to the returned directive object.

```
.directive('jqGrid',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('gridController',['$scope',function($scope){                     
                    $scope.btns=false;
                    $scope.details_tab=false;
                    $scope.currentid={id:''};
                    $scope.setId=function(id){
                        $scope.currentid.id=id; // change 
                    };
}]);

  onSelectRow : function (rowid, status) {
                                              scope.btns=true;
                                               scope.details_tab=true;
                                                scope.currentid.id=rowid;
                                                }
```